# Android long to date conversion goes wrong

Tags: android

I oonvert a date into long.
Sat May 05 2012 16:39:00 -> 1336235940000

Then I convert this back to a date and I get  6-4-112 16:39

```
long tmp = 1336235940000l;  
Date d = new Date(tmp);
int aYear = d.getYear();
int aMonth = d.getMonth();
int aDay = d.getDay();
int aHour = d.getHours();
int aMinutes = d.getMinutes();
String str_dateA = aDay + "-" + aMonth + "-" + aYear + " " + aHour + ":" + aMinutes;
Log.i("longtodate", str_dateA + "");
```

aMonth could be 4 if the first month is 0, but how can day be 6 instead of 5?? year is 112?
What is wrong??

Comment: @Jack: `Date(timestamp)` expects **milliseconds**, read the manual, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.getDay()` gives DAY_OF_WEEK, not the day in the month.

And Saturday is the 6th day of the week.

Comment: `getYear()` gives you year since 1900, which is 1900 + 112 = 2012.

Comment: thanks! now I can make it work, but do you have any better solutions to get the year, month... from a long type?

Comment: sure, use `Calendar`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html